# How to replace a value in Pandas Column multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe `df1`

```
Questions                             Purpose
what is scientific name of <input>    scientific name
what is english name of <input>       english name
```

And I have 2 lists as below:

```
name1 = ['salt','water','sugar']
name2 = ['sodium chloride','dihydrogen monoxide','sucrose']
```

I want to create a new dataframe by replacing `<input>` by values in the list depends on the purpose.

if purpose is english name replace `<input>` by values in `name2`
else replace `<input>` by `name1`.

**Expected Output DataFrame:**

```
Questions                                   Purpose
what is scientific name of salt             scientific name
what is scientific name of water            scientific name
what is scientific name of sugar            scientific name
what is english name of sodium chloride     english name
what is english name of dihydrogen monoxide english name
what is english name of sucrose             english name
```

**My Efforts**

```
questions = []
purposes = []

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Purpose'] == 'scientific name':
        for name in name1:
            ques = row['Questions'].replace('<input>', name)
            questions.append(ques)
            purposes.append(row['Purpose'])
    else:
        for name in name2:
           ques = row['Questions'].replace('<input>', name)
           questions.append(ques)
           purposes.append(row['Purpose'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Questions':questions, 'Purpose':purposes})
```

The above code produces expected output. But it is too slow as I have many questions on the original `dataframe`. (I have multiple purposes too but for now, I'm sticking with only 2).

I am looking for a more efficient solution which may get rid of `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it is by iterating over the `Questions` with a list comprehension and replacing `<input>` with the corresponding `name`. In order to repeat each `Question` as many times as fields thre are in `namesx` you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

names = [name1, name2]
new = [[i.replace('<input>', j), purpose] 
                       for row, purpose, name in zip(df.Questions, df.Purpose, names) 
                       for i,j in zip(cycle([row]), name)]

pd.DataFrame(new, columns=df.columns) 

                                    Questions          Purpose
0              what is scientific name of salt  scientific name
1             what is scientific name of water  scientific name
2             what is scientific name of sugar  scientific name
3      what is english name of sodium chloride     english name
4  what is english name of dihydrogen monoxide     english name
5              what is english name of sucrose     english name
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something like below using `pd.concat()` you can try:

```
names = name1+name2
df_new = pd.concat([df.loc[df.Purpose.eq('scientific name')]]*len(name1))\
    .append(pd.concat([df.loc[df.Purpose.eq('english name')]]*len(name2)),ignore_index=True)

for e,i in enumerate(names):
    df_new.Questions.loc[e]=df_new.Questions.loc[e].replace('<input>',i)
print(df_new)

                                     Questions          Purpose
0              what is scientific name of salt  scientific name
1             what is scientific name of water  scientific name
2             what is scientific name of sugar  scientific name
3      what is english name of sodium chloride     english name
4  what is english name of dihydrogen monoxide     english name
5              what is english name of sucrose     english name
```